# AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, gmail, mailmessage

I know there have been more questions about this, but they dont seem to work for me.

I followed the following tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hlZexx2gbNs.

I want to make an email send form in MVC ASP.NET.
Everything in seemed to work, except for the last step. I had to change the RouteConfig, but I dont have a routeconfig.

I think I need to change this for this to work, but I dont know where to change this. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this issue?

If there is a good solution for this on another question, let me know.

This is de code I use for the view:

```
@model smoothboard.Models.gmail

@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<h4>Email</h4>
<hr />

<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "EmailSetup", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Naar:
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(gmail=>gmail.To)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Verzend">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    }
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

This is the code I use to send the mail:

```
public class EmailSetupController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    string from = new string("hans31833@gmail.com");
    string subject = new string("Geregistreerd");
    string body = new string("Je hebt je ingeschreven voor de nieuwsbrief!");
    public IActionResult Index(smoothboard.Models.gmail gmail, string from)
    {

        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(from, gmail.To);
        mm.Subject = subject;
        mm.Body = body;
        mm.IsBodyHtml = false;

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;

        NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("hans31833@gmail.com", "hans1234hans");
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtp.Credentials = nc;
        smtp.Send(mm);
        ViewBag.MailMessage = "Mail is verzonden";
        return View();
    }
}
```

This is what I use for my model:

```
namespace smoothboard.Models
{
public class gmail
{
    public string To { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: You have `public IActionResult Index` method definition with same HTTP method (GET), this causing ambiguous matching. Either replace one of your action method name or use `[HttpPost]` attribute instead.

Comment: How would I use this method then?

Comment: Make the second action method use HTTP POST method, as mentioned in answer below.

Comment: Ah i see, it worked, but now it says that      MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(from, gmail.To);     cannot be null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem mentioned by exception message is straightforward: you have 2 action methods with same name and same HTTP method (by default HTTP method is `GET`, which implicitly uses `[HttpGet]`):

```
// first action with GET method
public IActionResult Index() { ... }

// ambiguous matching here because this also uses GET method
public IActionResult Index(smoothboard.Models.gmail gmail, string from) { ... }
```

Since you have `BeginForm` helper which uses `FormMethod.Post`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "EmailSetup", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Then you must decorate the second `Index` action with parameters using `[HttpPost]` attribute to distinguish its HTTP method:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(smoothboard.Models.gmail gmail, string from)
{
    MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(from, gmail.To);
    mm.Subject = subject;
    mm.Body = body;
    mm.IsBodyHtml = false;

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;

    NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("hans31833@gmail.com", "hans1234hans");
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    smtp.Credentials = nc;
    smtp.Send(mm);
    ViewBag.MailMessage = "Mail is verzonden";
    return View();
}
```

Comment: thanks, but now it says that MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(from, gmail.To); cannot be null